# Create users identified by the same password as another user in MariaDB 10.0.X

Tags: mariadb, users, mariadb-10.1

How do I create users with the same password as another user in MariaDB 10.x?

I do not know the password of the existing user , so i want to use same hashed password as existing, also do need to replica of the user with different host , meaning same grants.

Comment: Create a "Role"?

Answer (score 1):

`CREATE USER` has number of forms. You can provide the plain password as well as already hashed value stored in the engine:

```
authentication_option:
  IDENTIFIED BY 'string' 
| IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'password_hash'
| IDENTIFIED {VIA|WITH} authentication_plugin
| IDENTIFIED {VIA|WITH} authentication_plugin {USING|AS} 'authentication_string'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create user with any password
2. Update table `mysql.users` and copy password from one user to another
3. Flush users data.